# Transaction in snowflake stored procedures

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My first stored proc in snowflake, trying to use transaction in one of the sample stored proc, please help to fix the error and why? "**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in GET_ROW_COUNT at ' BEGIN TRANSACTION;' position 8**"
trying to follow the document: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html

Here is the proc.

```
  create or replace procedure get_row_count(table_name VARCHAR)
  returns float not null
  language javascript
  as
  $$
  var row_count = 0;
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  // Dynamically compose the SQL statement to execute.
  var sql_command = "select count(*) from " + TABLE_NAME;
  // Run the statement.
  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
         {
         sqlText: sql_command
         }
      );
  var res = stmt.execute();
  // Get back the row count. Specifically, ...
  // ... get the first (and in this case only) row from the result set ...
  res.next();
  // ... and then get the returned value, which in this case is the number of
  // rows in the table.
  row_count = res.getColumnValue(1);
  return row_count;
  COMMIT ;
  $$
  ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call COMMIT and BEGIN TRANSACTION using snowflake.execute() as they are SQL commands:

```
 create or replace procedure get_row_count(table_name VARCHAR)
  returns float not null
  language javascript
  as
  $$
  var row_count = 0;
  snowflake.execute({ sqlText: 'BEGIN TRANSACTION' });
  // Dynamically compose the SQL statement to execute.
  var sql_command = "select count(*) from " + TABLE_NAME;
  // Run the statement.
  var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
         {
         sqlText: sql_command
         }
      );
  var res = stmt.execute();
  // Get back the row count. Specifically, ...
  // ... get the first (and in this case only) row from the result set ...
  res.next();
  // ... and then get the returned value, which in this case is the number of
  // rows in the table.
  row_count = res.getColumnValue(1);

  snowflake.execute({ sqlText: 'COMMIT' }); 
  return row_count;
  $$
  ;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, In the Snowflake documentations, it was only mentioned as just BEGIN and COMMIT because the language was NOT java script based, its plain snowflake.